# Service account impersonation is not working via python script in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, impersonation

I am trying to impersonate a service account which is my compute service account to another service account but somehow getting issue at the python code below

```
    ########################## BQ Execution ##############################
# 1. This program is Creating Bucket Path
#######################################################################
import google
import google.auth
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials
from google.cloud import storage
import sys
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

credentials,project_id=google.auth.default()

target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
service_account = 'abc@prj.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

target_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(source_credentials=credentials,target_principal=service_account,target_scopes=target_scopes,delegates=[],lifetime=3600)

print("impersonated service_account: {}".format(target_credentials.signer_email))


project_id=sys.argv[1]
bucket_name=sys.argv[2]
path=sys.argv[3]
gcs_client = storage.Client(project=project_id, credentials=target_credentials)
bucket= gcs_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(path)
blob.upload_from_string('', content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8')
```

Now when i run this script i am getting below issue , please let me know what else i need to add to get this token. is it mandatory at all here.. :

```
impersonated service_account: impersonated@sa.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/impersonated_credentials.py", line 108, in _make_iam_token_request
    token = token_response["accessToken"]
KeyError: 'accessToken'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bucket-new.py", line 38, in <module>
    bucket= gcs_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 765, in get_bucket
    retry=retry,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 956, in reload
    retry=retry,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 214, in reload
    _target_object=self,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 375, in _get_resource
    _target_object=_target_object,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/_http.py", line 78, in api_request
    return call()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 290, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 188, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 480, in api_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 338, in _make_request
    method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 376, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 474, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/impersonated_credentials.py", line 242, in refresh
    self._update_token(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/impersonated_credentials.py", line 273, in _update_token
    iam_endpoint_override=self._iam_endpoint_override,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/impersonated_credentials.py", line 120, in _make_iam_token_request
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials: No access token or invalid expiration in response.', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",\n        "domain": "googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "method": "google.iam.credentials.v1.IAMCredentials.GenerateAccessToken",\n          "service": "iamcredentials.googleapis.com"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')
```

Comment: Where are you running the script?

Comment: The identity that this code is running under does not have permission to impersonate the service account. The service account requires `Service Account Token Creator : roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`. You also need two APIs enabled: `iamcredentials.googleapis.com` and `cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com` This article will help you: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/